# Shell script using curl to loop through urls

Tags: bash, loops, curl

I've been trying to create a simple script that will take a list of queries from a .txt file, append the main url variable, then scrape the content and output it to a text file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="example.com/?q="
for i in $(cat query.txt); do
    content=$(curl -o $url $i)
    echo $url $i
    echo $content >> output.txt
done
```

list:

```
images
news
stuff
other
```

error log:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: other; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
example.com/?q= other
```

If I use this command straight from the command line I get some output into the file:

```
curl -L http://example.com/?q=other >> output.txt
```

Ultimately I would like the output to be:

```
fetched:    http://example.com/?q=other
content:    the output of the page

followed by the next query in the list.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use more quotes !

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Try this instead :

```
url="example.com/?q="
for i in $(cat query.txt); do
    content="$(curl -s "$url/$i")"
    echo "$content" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: I guess that should have been painfully obvious. :p 

Thanks very much! :)

Comment: each iteration, the previous output is clearing from output.txt? do you know how to keep it?

Answer (score 5):

You've got nested quotes, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=https://www.google.fr/?q=
while read query
do
    content=$(curl "{$url}${query}")
    echo $query
    echo $content >> output.txt
done < query.txt
```