# Bash scripting for create array from file and use each value on a curl URL

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on a bash script and I got a list of IP's that I wanted to add one by one in a CURL command.
For example given list on a file named list.txt

```
8.8.8.8
10.10.10.10
136.34.24.22
192.168.10.32
```

I wanted to add each value on curl command

```
curl -k -u $user:$password "https://logservice/jobs" --data-urlencode 'search=search index=test $ARRAYVALUE | head 1' > output.txt
```

Where $ARRAYVALUE is the IP address to be used on the command.

I will appreciate any hint.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered trying to look up how to [read a file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash) in bash?

Comment: Also, you should read about [the difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Comment: Why do you want an array?  Just to `while read ip; do ... ; done < list.txt`

Comment: I believe all you need is simple `xargs -I{} curl ... {}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script using curl to loop through urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16131321/608639), [How to execute the same curl request on a sequence of server IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47075974/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to:

- map each line of a "list.txt" to an item of an array
- loop over the newly created array inserting items one by one into your command invocation

Consider this, heavily commented, snippet. Look especially at `mapfile` and how variable is used in `curl` invocation, surrounded by *double* quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare a (non-associative) array 
# each item is indexed numerically, starting from 0
declare -a ips
#put proper values here
user="userName"
password="password"
# put file into array, one line per array item
mapfile -t ips < list.txt

# counter used to access items with given index in an array
ii=0
# ${#ips[@]} returns array length 
# -lt makes "less than" check 
# while loops as long as condition is true
while [ ${ii} -lt ${#ips[@]} ] ; do 
  # ${ips[$ii]} accesses array item with the given (${ii}) index
  # be sure to use __double__ quotes around variable, otherwise it will not be expanded (value will not be inserted) but treated as a string
  curl -k -u $user:$password "https://logservice/jobs" --data-urlencode "search=search index=test ${ips[$ii]} | head -1" > output.txt
  # increase counter to avoid infinite loop
  # and access the next item in an array
  ((ii++))
done
```

You may read about `mapfile` in [GNU Bash reference: Built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

You may read about creating and accessing arrays in [GNU Bash reference: Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

Check this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) about quotes in `bash`.

I hope you found this answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
function FN()
{
  filename=$1

  declare -a IPs_ARRAY
  i=0
  user=$2
  password=$3

  while read ip
  do
        IPs_ARRAY[$i]=$ip
        echo ${IPs_ARRAY[$i]}
        # Uncomment for your actions ::
        #curl -k -u $user:$password "https://logservice/jobs" --data-urlencode 'search=search index=test ${IPs_ARRAY[$i]} | head 1' > output.txt
        (( i++ ))

  done < $filename
}

#############
### MAIN ###
###########
read -p "Enter username: " username
read -p "Enter password: " password
# Call your function 
filename="list.txt"
FN $filename $username $password
```